# Approximations of functionals

Tags: functional-analysis

The distance between a point and a set in a metric space or in a normed space is used in approximation of functionals (i read it in functional analysis book) can any body explain this please as i am unaware of approximation of functions

Comment: This is a bit vague.

Comment: I m not getting your openion

Comment: Your question doesn't have enough information to be able to attempt an answer.